# Forking to Run Code in a Child Process With Perl's Dancer

Tags: perl, perl-module, fork, dancer

I have a Dancer app in perl that handles get/post requests.

One of my example routes is below:

```
post '/handle_data' => sub {

    # perform some calculations
    ...
    # store some data
    ...
    # do some long running tasks
    ...
};
```

My question: is there an easy way to do the long running tasks in another process without blocking the request?

I've tried `fork and return` in the parent process, with an `exit` after the long running tasks for the child, but that all seems to block the response from being sent until the child completes.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I ended up switching to a full-fledged job server, specifically the perl version of [Gearman](http://gearman.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the fork and return appears to work for me.

I tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Dancer;

get '/' => sub {
    fork and return "Content!\n";

    sleep 10; # do your actual work here
    warn "Child process done\n";
    exit;
};

dance;
```

Running that via the standalone server, or via plackup/Starman, works as expected - the "Content!\n" is returned to the user's browser immediately, and the request is over; the forked process hangs around for ten seconds sleeping, then issues the warning (visible on the terminal) then exits.

Comment: Through trial and error debugging, this works as I thought it would.
My issue was that I was printing out debug info before the response headers... :)

Comment: I have a question about this: Does this fork the entire dancer process or just the function under the route? I am not familar with threads in perl, but I use Dancer for many projects and this could be useful some time.

Comment: It forks the whole process; that's why you need the `exit` in my example, otherwise that forked child process, once it left the route handler, could hang around waiting for a new connection.

Comment: @DavidPrecious I have an issue with the forking and exitting...

I'm seeing a lot of plackup workers listed as defunct once I start using this method.

Comment: @Blaskovicz That's because there's no "reaper".  Something like this should handle that asynchronously `$SIG{CHLD} = sub { wait };`