# Dancer Under Plackup and Starman; forking leaves defunct starman processes?

Tags: perl, perl-module, fork, dancer, plack

As a follow up to my other question here: [Forking to Run Code in a Child Process With Perl's Dancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614498/forking-to-run-code-in-a-child-process-with-perls-dancer) - how do I fork a request running under plackup/starman/dancer without causing the child to be left in the zombie state?

eg of what I'm trying to do:

```
post '/handle_data' => sub {

# perform some calculations
...
# store some data
...
fork and return; # parent request
# do some long running tasks
...
exit; # child
```

};

... causes the starman worker to be recycled, but a leftover plackup process to be defunct.

From perlipc, I have also tried setting `$SIG{CHLD} = "IGNORE"`, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

When forking you'd have the parent process not exit but rather wait for the child pid(s).
If I recall `fork` is either setting a return value or a special variable with the pid of the child; so you need to catch that. Oh and register an `$SIG{INT}` handler that similarly waits.

You're probably looking to use [waitpid](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/waitpid.html).

Comment: Yes. A process whose parent does not wait on it becomes a defunct/zombie when it exits, init (pid 1) adopts it, but it doesn't get cleaned out of the process table until you reboot.